# Why does my SQL Server database do not save the data using a procedure - C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to make a procedure and call it when I need to insert some data.

When I execute the application and click "save", the application does not respond for at least 15 seconds before returning to normal. But the data isn't saved.

I made a test procedure and some test functions to test it.

The connection string:

```
public static string Cn = 
       "Data Source = THIAGO\\SERVIDORSQL; Initial Catalog = DBClinica; Integrated Security = true";
```

The data layer code to insert test data:

```
public string Adicionar_Teste(Dados_Pacientes dados_Pacientes)
{
    string resp = "";

    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();

    try
    {
        sqlConnection.ConnectionString = Conexao.Cn;//cn is the SQL DATABASE path
        sqlConnection.Open();

        // SQL command
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
        sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConnection;
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "ProcAdicionar_Teste";
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter parTeste = new SqlParameter();
        parTeste.ParameterName = "@Teste";
        parTeste.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
        parTeste.Size = 10;
        parTeste.Value = dados_Pacientes.Nome;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(parTeste);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return resp = ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open) 
            sqlConnection.Close();
    }

    return resp;
}
```

The business layer:

```
public static string AdicionarTeste(string teste)
{
    Dados_Pacientes dados = new Dados_Pacientes();
    dados.Nome = teste;

    return dados.Adicionar_Teste(dados);
}
```

The form method called when the user clicks in 'save':

```
private void AdicionarTeste()
{
    string x = TextBoxNomeDoPaciente.Text;
    Negocios_Pacientes.AdicionarTeste(x);
}
```

[SQL Server name and path:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKlv4.png)

and

[SQL Server database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCBrl.png)

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[procAdicionar_Teste]
    @Teste VARCHAR(10)
AS
    INSERT INTO Teste (Teste) 
    VALUES (@Teste)
```

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: No, just crash the application and back to normal

Comment: Crash or just pause?

Comment: Sorry, but what is SP code?

Comment: sometimes crash and sometimes just doesn't do anything

Comment: I edited and put the SP

Comment: You're not calling a method to actually contact the database? Probably you want to add `sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery` after you add the parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not executing the command. You need to add below statement at the end of the try block.

```
sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: OMG. Thank you! I've searched for this for 3 days.

Comment: @EverytimeIdid, Glad, it helped